# What is the full collector number of the MTG card "Aesthetic Consultation" from Unhinged Foil-only Booster card

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What is the full collector number of the MTG card "Aesthetic Consultation" from Unhinged Foil-only Booster card?

It reads something like '48/140 Disrobing'. I am particularly curious about the last word.

https://scryfall.com/card/unh/48%E2%98%85/aesthetic-consultation

As well as Farewell to Arms. Is it '56/140 Squizzie'?
https://cards.scryfall.io/large/front/4/7/47b61c3a-5e76-4529-9878-603e49c82743.jpg?1562488372

Comment: Your title and first link are about "Aesthetic Consultation", but your first paragraph asks about "Richard Garfield, Ph.D."  Which card are you interested in?

Comment: Fixed the body of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The collector number of that card is just 48/140. The word "Disrobing" is part of a hidden piece of text in the set with one word on each card. The text can be read by putting the cards in reverse alphabetical order by name, starting with [Zzzyxas's Abyss](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zzzyxas%27s%20Abyss). The text starts with "Here are some more cards that didn't make it." Aesthetic Consultation's name is near the beginning of the alphabet, so its word is near the end of that text. Along with ["Ach! Hans, Run!"](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=%22Ach%21%20Hans%2C%20Run%21%22) and [_____](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=_____), it says "Disrobing Scepter (again!)". Similarly, Farewell to Arms, along with [Face to Face](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Face%20to%20Face) says "Squizzle Nabizzle".